# How to split a .bak file on Google Drive?

Tags: mysql, download, google-drive-api, database-backups

I'm trying to download a really large .bak file from Google Drive that is over 600 GB. Is there anyway to split it before downloading?

Comment: Some systems will allow you to specify how many lines of the file to take, but I think we did that with csv...

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] if you are having issues with downloading the file with your code.

Comment: Do you prefer smaller cuter chunks or is there a specific issue?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to split it up? Why not just download the whole file to begin with?  Are you having an issue with that?  If so please post your code.  There should be no issue with downloading a 600 GB file.

Comment: My question isn't actually code-related. But maybe you can split a file using the api? I don't know.

Comment: The reason why I want to split it up is because I only have 200 GB on my hardrive.

Comment: Still not clear are you saying you only want a small subset of the file? And you don't intend to recombine? And what is this .bak file?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to split it you can download a file that large.

That being said you can use [Partial download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#partial_download) Partial download involves downloading only a specified portion of a file. You can specify the portion of the file you want to download by using a byte range with the Range header.

For example:

```
Range: bytes=500-999
```

It is not clear if all of the Google client libraries actually support it though. You may need to do this the hard way.

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ###accessToken###", "Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(start, start+length)}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
fh = io.BytesIO(res.content)
return fh.getvalue()
```

Comment: How would you recombine?

Comment: @P.Salmon I wouldn't I would just download the whole file to begin with.  You can download a file up to 5TB no problem.  The only reason i can see to use partial would be if you didnt need the full file.

Comment: @DaImTo but how would _one_ recombine the file?